# Invoking procedure returned by function

Tags: delphi, pascal

Having this:

```
procedure Foo;
begin
end;

function Bar: TProcedure;
begin
  Result := Foo;
end;
```

The following compiles:

```
var
  tmp: TProcedure;
begin
  tmp := Bar();
  tmp();
```

...but the following doesn't compile in Delphi:

```
Bar()();
```

Is there a reason for this "limitation"? Does `Bar()();` syntax compile in some other "flavour" of Pascal? Would `Bar()();` syntax compile in some other context?

Comment: How about `(Bar())()`?

Comment: Nice trick, but I prefer `Bar()()`.

Comment: You prefer the version that doesn't compile?

Comment: (Bar())() doesn't compile either for me (D7).

Comment: @Fenistil No. I was just trying to offer an alternative, guessing that this was an issue with the parsing. It seems that there is a bug, but not quite as I imagined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a limitation in the grammar of the language. The statement `Bar()()` should be valid. So, I believe that this is a compiler bug in older versions of Delphi. This program compiles in Delphi 2010 and later:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure Foo;
begin
end;

function Bar: TProcedure;
begin
  Result := Foo;
end;

begin
  Bar()();
end.
```

It is quite possible that the compiler bug was fixed before Delphi 2010, it's just that's the version that I have to hand. It seems that the bug is still present in Delphi 7, and fixed by Delphi 2010. So the bug appears to have been fixed somewhere in between those two versions.

**Update 1**

Marco reports that the Free Pascal compiler accepts `Bar()()`.

**Update 2**

Rudy has done some testing and reports that the bug is still present in D2007 so the fix was either D2009 and D2010. My instincts tell me that Embarcadero would have discovered the problem themselves when adding the anonymous methods feature and that would have been the trigger for the fix to be made.

Comment: In FPC it also works. Btw, the fun begins when assigning and when Bar has the same signature as foo.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort It would all have been a lot simpler if procedure and function calls required `()`

Comment: @David: Just tried in D2007 (I only have D2007 and DXE..DXE6 installed here), and there it gives an error. In XE it works fine, just like in your D2010. So the fix was in D2009 or D2010.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: If the code could be ambiguous, just use `@` when assigning, or, if that is still too ambiguous, use `Addr()`.

Comment: I added another level of indirection - 
type
  TFunc = function : TProcedure;

procedure Baz;
begin
end;

function Bar: TProcedure;
begin
  result := Baz;
end;

function Foo: TFunc;
begin
  result := Bar;
end;

begin
  Foo()()();
end.
           and it will still compile in XE2.

Answer (score 6):

Simply call as

```
TProcedure(Bar());
```

Comment: It works fine in {$mode Delphi}. Lazarus works default in $mode objfpc, one of the biggest differences between those two modes is that objfpc mode tries to disambiguate certain procvar related constructs. Like requiring always @ to take the address of a function, and () to call a parameterless function.

Comment: @marco Once you require () to call, why ask for @ to take address?

Comment: Phew, that's all so long ago. Maybe we don't always require (), only in one specific case.